# Difference between 2 byte arrays as stream in webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, arrays

I'm working on legacy code. No colleagues whom to ask...

From one api I'm getting an byte array as response:

```
Ç¡–¶Àá3`‰1wñžbF
```

While my Api response is:

```
¶–¡ÇáÀ`3‰1wñžbF
```

It seems to close, yet so far away...

I'm getting an base64 and convert it to byte array.

```
var key = await _httpclient.GetKey(id);
return Convert.FromBase64(key);
```

And in my controller

```
var response = await _aesService.GetLicense(id, cancellationToken);
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response, "application/octet-stream");
```

Where as in my webapi I have a BinaryFormatter:

```
public class BinaryMediaTypeFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    private static readonly Type _supportedType = typeof(byte[]);

    public BinaryMediaTypeFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return type == _supportedType;
    }

    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var buff = (byte[])value;
        return writeStream.WriteAsync(buff, 0, buff.Length, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And in the Register from WebApiConfig

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Enable support for CORS headers
        config.EnableCors();

        // Web API configuration and services
        config.Formatters.Clear();

        // Configure JSON formatter
        var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        jsonSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        var jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter { SerializerSettings = jsonSettings };

        // Add support for JSON POSTs without proper content-type
        jsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
        jsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

        config.Formatters.Add(jsonFormatter);                   // Add JSON formatter
        config.Formatters.Add(new BinaryMediaTypeFormatter());  // Add custom formatter for Byte[] application/octet-stream

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

What am I missing, or am I wasting my time here? It feels like I'm almost there, but I am missing something...

In desperate need for your help :)

Comment: Consider their response as `0123456789ABCDE`. Yours is `3210547689ABCDE`. Maybe there is a bit of shifting to do?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: How would I do that? I have no experience in this. Wouldn't it (or should I say: Shouldn't it) directly the same. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: I've tried according the following anser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440938/c-sharp-left-shift-an-entire-byte-array however, this doesn't seem to help. Should i try for bit per bit? And would it then always be the same? This feels more like a bandage then fixing the problem..