# How to perform bit copy in C# or byte array left shift operation

Tags: c#, bit

I want to store information in concatenated fashion in a byte array (2 Bits + 6 Byte + 14 Bits) but I have no idea how to do it.  With `Buffer.Blockcopy`, I can work with bytes, not bits. Moreover, 6 Byte data is already a part of data structure and referenced everywhere, so I don't wish to change that variable. I was thinking of declaring a byte then making a binary string cutting and concatenating, but I think it will be a very bad implementation. There must be a better and efficient way of doing this.

Here is the C# script that I am currently using, but I think there must be better and efficient way to do this.

```
byte[] ARC = new byte[7]{0x00,0xB1,0x1C,0x3D,0x4C,0x1A,0xEF};

RotateLeft(ARC);
RotateLeft(ARC);
RotateLeft(ARC);
RotateLeft(ARC);
RotateLeft(ARC);
RotateLeft(ARC);
 //temp = Convert.ToString(ARC[1], 2).PadLeft(8,'0');
//MessageBox.Show(temp.ToString());
//MessageBox.Show(ByteArrayToString(ARC));
ARC[0] |= 1 << 6;
ARC[0] |= 1 << 7;
byte SB = 0x02;
string Hex = Convert.ToString(SB, 2);
Hex = Hex.Substring(0, 2);
Hex += "000000";
byte SB_processed = Convert.ToByte(Hex,2);
SB_processed |= 1 << 0;
SB_processed |= 1 << 1;
SB_processed |= 1 << 2;
SB_processed |= 1 << 3;
SB_processed |= 1 << 4;
SB_processed |= 1 << 5;

ARC[0] &= SB_processed;
MessageBox.Show(ByteArrayToString(ARC));
```

Logic for Left shifting taken from this reference.
[c# - left shift an entire byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440938/c-sharp-left-shift-an-entire-byte-array)

Comment: What you have tried yet!!Adding some code will help others to answer your uncleared question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't well understand your question, but here I show you how to concatenate bits.

```
        byte bits2 = 0b_000000_10;
        byte bits6 = 0b_00_101100;
        ushort bits14 = 0b_00_10110010001110;

        uint concatenated = ((uint)bits2 << 20) + ((uint)bits6 << 14) + (uint)bits14;

        uint test = 0b_00_10_101100_10110010001110;
        if (concatenated == test‬)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ok");
        }
```

Comment: This looks useful..But I am getting syntax error "0b_" notation.Is their any .NET framework constraint ? I am using VS2010

Comment: @Sudhanwa Deo, binary literals are supported from C# 7

Comment: -->Are you using C# 7 compiler ?

Comment: Very much advanced stuff, I am working with VS2010.Thanks for your solution